# How can I improve PHP CLI output speed

Tags: command-line-interface, php

Recently discovered merits in running php scripts via cli, and while the work-flow is faster I've found that executing php scripts via cli is much slower than just refreshing the browser.

```
echo 'hello'; // >1 second cli vs <10 millisecond in browser
```

I understand php environment is required to load on every execution call (via php -f), whereas in the browser, php is already loaded into memory via the webserver.

I'm looking for a solution to speed php startup time.  Apache is running.

The goal is to speed up the output via a text editors output, which by default runs php -f.

I'm hoping there is a way to either I pre-load php or pipe into apache directly maybe by using the fast-cgi stream directly, but how?

Comment: it's impossibile it takes 1 sec to load php cli. especially because php cli doesn't need to be loaded. Maybe it's something related to output_buffer. Try disabling it via php.ini, but i doubt

Comment: How did you measure the CLI speed? What did you measure?

Comment: What scenario are you running into where the initialization time of cli php is an issue?

Comment: @Geoff: Please post details of how you timed both approaches

Comment: Do this command: `time php yourscript.php`

Comment: I am suspecting you are getting a bottleneck somewhere else in your system: I just put a simple test together:

`<?php
$time = microtime(true);
echo "Hello World\n";
$runTime = microtime(true) - $time;
echo "Execution time: " . $runTime . "\n";
`
And run from the command line I get:

Hello World
`Execution time: 3.814697265625E-5`

(in other words 0.0000381469 seconds) from the command line.

Comment: @aaron: your answer imo was perfect, better than a comment

Comment: @yes123 Yeah it didn't really answer the question/problem though, thats why I meant it as a comment :)

Comment: The time it takes to render a php script is the same, no matter how you run, after all it is still php.  the problem is the speed in which the output is displayed.

Comment: The CLI scripts are running via 'php -f' option.  It is the same if you run it this way from command prompt or via an IDE such as scite, sublime2, netbeans

Comment: the problem is calling php -f, as it has to load the php environment everytime you want to execute your script.  Fresh loading php takes ruffly a second.

Comment: @geoff can you answer the question asked by @cez, and/or provide output of what @datasage suggested? (time php yourscript.php)

Comment: If you're adventurous you could set up php-fpm (php daemon) and write your own C program that accepts a PHP file from stdin, creates a valid fast-cgi request over a socket to php-fpm, and spits back the results.

Comment: @datasage calling php -f file.php.

Comment: @arron php render time is 0.00015.  It is not a problem with php rendering it is a problem with loading php initially to render the file

Comment: @caz - stopwatch.  In a browser I cannot click start/stop fast enough and via php -f it takes around 1 second(1.08)

Comment: The test environment is windows 7 64bit, but the problem is universal to all operating systems

Comment: If you prefix any command with `time` it will measure the time it takes for the command to execute. Interestingly there is a delay on the first execution `real 0m0.743s
user 0m0.016s
sys 0m0.018s` But not on later ones `real 0m0.027s
user 0m0.020s
sys 0m0.006s`

Comment: @konforce php daemon is the right idea, and would take care of the pre-load issue.  Maybe someway to tap into fast-cgi directly?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running php on **windows** and have **curl** enabled you might be experiencing a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50410) which was reintroduced in 5.3.6, and also existed before 5.3.5. The libcurl library takes ages to load when on windows.

Comment: Using PHP 5.3.3.  Will test on latest version.